# How to get index of a point in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using "Time data with irregular intervals" chart of Highcharts. As you know when mouse moves over points of line the formatter function runs and shows some information. I want to know index of the point that mouse moves over it. So if mouse moves over first point of the line, tooltip shows "1" and the second point shows "2" and so on. thnx.

Comment: Edgar's answer appears to be the best, no processing required.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This worked for me using v2.2:

```
this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Simple!

Comment: excellent, short and simple!!!. although i don't think you need the **this.point** (in the parenthesis ) , only **this**

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer is an ugly hack.

Comment: Plain and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

One way is to pre-process the data to contain a property with the index. In the Snow-depth example you could do a preparation like this:

```
function prepare(dataArray) {
    return dataArray.map(function (item, index) {
        return {x: item[0], y: item[1], myIndex: index};
    });
};
```

to convert the array of `[x, y]` to be an object like `{ x: x, y: y, myIndex: i}`. Then its easy to pick up that index in the formatter with:

```
formatter: function() {
     return 'point ' + this.point.myIndex;
}
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLFRG/)

Comment: This code seems more faster. I test it in my project As soon as I can. Thnx eolsson.

Comment: Yes, it should be faster than searching for the index, but will use up more memory.

Comment: Wow.. Now I came to know that I can add more attributes apart from name,x,y,note in object array. +1 for that

Comment: While this should be marginally faster, @Edgar's solution below is more general. In some code where the data is not constant (for example if you're filtering data points and some can get removed), the indices can become stale.  Speed should not be an issue unless the dataset is huge.

Answer (score 7):

For the record your can do it directly in a nice way

It is store in:

```
this.points[0].point.x
```

Comment: I can tell you exactly why this got downvoted: because it relies on the content of X to be an index. In my case X was a date, so I got the dates. However using `seriesMapping` I mapped the third column of my CSV to an actual index and then accessed it using this line :) +1 from me

Answer (score 3):

Since the data is sorted you can use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

A binary search should perform well even for large number of points (from the wikipedia article: "For example, to search a list of one million items takes as many as one million iterations with linear search, but **never more than twenty iterations with binary search**."

Example:

```
var bsComparator = function(a, b) {
    if (a.x < b.x) { return -1; }
    if (a.x > b.x) { return 1; }
    return 0;
};
var binarySearch = function(series_data, point) {
    var low = 0, high = series_data.length - 1,
        i, comparison;
    while (low <= high) {
        i = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
        comparison = bsComparator(series_data[i], point);
        if (comparison < 0) { low = i + 1; continue; }
        if (comparison > 0) { high = i - 1; continue; }
        return i;
    }
    return null;
};


tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var pointIndex = binarySearch(this.series.data, this.point);
        return "Point index: " + pointIndex;
    }
}
```

(the binarySearch function above is inspired by http://www.dweebd.com/javascript/binary-search-an-array-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you only need the xAxis value (i.e. time). Use:
`this.xData.indexOf(point.x)`

this.points will be grouped in larger series so would need a deeper search through points[0]...points[n].

Answer (score 1):

This is all that worked for me on Highstock JS v4.2.4:

```
var index = this.points[0].point.dataGroup.start;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about as hacky as it comes, and will get slow as hell with alot of points, but it'll work. The general idea is to look through all the points in the series' data until you find the one matching the current point:

```
tooltip: {
     formatter: function() {
         for(var i=0;i<this.series.data.length;i++){
              var item = this.series.data[i];
              if(item.x == this.x && item.y == this.y)
               return 'point ' + i;
         }
         return 'not found'
     }
  }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fuv4h/

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But as you mentioned this code takes so much time to execute specially when line is full of points. BTW I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your point then you can simple access,
`this.point.index` or simply `this.index` if `this` refers to the point it self
to get access to its index,

In my case I always use this because its simpler then @Edgar solution, which is also great.