# how to get index of a point in Highcharts to use in an event?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In a Highcharts chart I want to know index of a point when clicking over it. 
The following code ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/9bwmrogg/1/) jfiddle version) does not work:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y+ ', index: ' + this.indexOf);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

[Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507673/how-to-get-index-of-a-point-in-highcharts) it is suggested to use indeOf, as I have done, but it seems to work only in formatter tooltip section. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `index`, a property Highcharts exposes on the Point object, not `indexOf`.

```
... ', index: ' + this.index );
```

`indexOf` is a function which can be called on an array. Here you have an individual point's object, not an array. (Notice how `indexOf` is called as a function in that question you've linked to).

[**Modified JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9bwmrogg/3/).

Comment: @tic I just noticed that myself and corrected it whilst you were commenting - well spotted though!